# Need Action when Video is complete in video Player

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, video, video-player

I need video player which give me some events when video will complete. So, I can start another video after completing one video

How can I achieve it ?

Actually, I want to do it in ionic project. So, html and js video player will helpful for me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can add listener to your video element

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
videos[0].addEventListener("ended", function() {
    videos[1].play(); // the second video on page will start as just the first video ended
}, true);
```